# How to upload AWS S3 file to YouTube API

Tags: php, json, amazon-s3, google-api, youtube-data-api

Here is a difficult one... I have managed to adapt the AWS API easily but Google's Oauth2 is not working in my code... I have tried adapting code from StackOverflow and other sources... I have tried the YouTube upload code generator to only fail the upload. I have tried other code available (older Youtube Data API (Google ^2.0)... My biggest problem is that some code examples    don't include the API Version which errors in Classes being unidentified... Other code plainly doesn't work... This is my weeks holy grail... Please advise.

```
<?php
    require_once '../aws/aws-autoloader.php';
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;

    $chunkSizeBytes = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 mb
    $streamName = 's3://gb-football-tribunal-live/1616710690-605d0c226862f-1-0.mp4';

    $s3client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'version' => 'latest',
        'key'     => 'MyS3Key',
        'secret'  => 'MyS3Secret',
        'region'  => 'eu-west-1' // if you need to set.
    ));
    $s3client->registerStreamWrapper();


    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('cGbYt');
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setScopes([
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
    ]);

    // Define service object for making API requests.
    $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    // Define the $video object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();

    // Add 'snippet' object to the $video object.
    $videoSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $videoSnippet->setCategoryId('17');
    $videoSnippet->setChannelId('UCC7fqHtOns6DtnR7QcaJMaw');
    $videoSnippet->setDescription('Testing of Test00001');
    $videoSnippet->setTags(['Football', 'Test']);
    $videoSnippet->setTitle('Test 00001');
    $video->setSnippet($videoSnippet);

    // Add 'status' object to the $video object.
    $videoStatus = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $videoStatus->setEmbeddable(true);
    $videoStatus->setLicense('youtube');
    $videoStatus->setPrivacyStatus('public');
    $videoStatus->setUploadStatus('uploaded');
    $video->setStatus($videoStatus);

    $queryParams = [
        'autoLevels' => false,
        'notifySubscribers' => true,
        'onBehalfOfContentOwner' => 'MyYoutTubeUserID',
        'onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel' => 'MyYouTubeChannelID',
        'stabilize' => false,
        'uploadType' => 'resumable',
        'alt' => 'json',
        'fields' => 'items(snippet(id))',
    ];

    $response = $service->videos->insert(
      'snippet,status',
      $video,
      $queryParams,
      array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($s3client),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
      )
    );
    print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use the official [`resumable_upload.php`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php). This is known to work. Then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: The code above does not run any OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flow at all. The OAuth flow is unavoidable since it's required for to acquire valid credentials data that allows you to issue a call to [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

Comment: What is your error exactly?